# Removing LXDE and installing GNOME 3

Tags: fedora, gnome3, lxde

I have a 700MB CD on which I'm putting the LXDE version of Fedora 18, and I wanted to know what happened when I remove LXDE and install GNOME 3, as the GNOME 3 version is too big for my CD.

Comment: If you are planning to install fedora from LXDE CD than it is better if you just install GNOME 3 and leave LXDE intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yum groupinstall GNOME`, and after everything is in place, remove the LXDE group.